# NA's produced when implementing dummy variables

Tags: r

I have a model which contains six variables with 5 levels each. I have included 4 dummies for each variable in the model. However, when I ask R to fit this linear model:

```
Model1 <- lm(Q1HEV ~ Detour15 + Detour10 + Detour5 + Detour0 + Fast20 + Fast15 + Fast10 + Fast5 + Charge6 + Charge4 + Charge2 + Charge1 + Range150 + Range250 + Range500 + Range750 + Costs5 + Costs25 + Costs40 + Costs50 + Price45 + Price30 + Price15 + Price10, data=Final_Data)
```

I get NA's for most dummies of Range, Cost and Price, together with the message: "Coefficients: (10 not defined because of singularities)"

I have read this might be due to multicollinearity, however I have done some checks and found no indication of multicollinearity.

As I really need the coefficients for these dummies as well, would anybody know how to solve or circumvent this problem?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us the structure of your object? Your variable should be a factor with x levels. In the end, your model should look like `lm(Q1HEV ~ Detour + Fast + charge + Range + Costs + Price, data = Final_Data)` or `lm(Q1HEV ~ .)`.

Comment: Could you post some data that you are working with? I would like to understand this one too.